# PHP&MySQL: Is it possible after running mysql_query with an insert to get the ID of the new row?

Tags: php, mysql, insert-query

Is there a straightforward way to run mysql_query with an insert and get the ID of the new row, for example in the return? Or will I have to do another query with select to check it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mysql_insert_id()

or

select last_insert_id()

Answer (score 2):

Simply call [mysql_insert_id](https://www.php.net/mysql_insert_id) after running mysql_query and you will get the ID.

Answer (score 2):

Try [mysql_insert _id()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)